# i can't set image in viewholder image in android

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, uri, adapter

I am try to set image in viewHolder imageview, I send image path in Adapter i can't set in imageview beacase i have convert in null value, i can't convert to file path to bitmap ,please help me.

```
    if(dataModel.getPhoto()!=null)
            {
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dataModel.getPhoto(), options);
                Log.e("decodefile",":"+bm);
                viewHolder.photo.setImageBitmap(bm);

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using BitmapFactory.Options correctly
Try this:-

```
public static Bitmap decodeBitmapFromFile(String filePath, int reqWidth,
        int reqHeight) {
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height
                / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        inSampleSize = heightRatio <= widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you share some more details?

May be your path is incorrect.Are you using **absolute path** of **image**?
If you are not using it change it to **absolute path**.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please us the comments section for that. Thank you.

Comment: @karandhillon How can they use the comment section when that requires 50 reputation points? Also, please see [When to flag an answer as “not an answer”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer)